# small white line at the bottom of the screen using p5.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, p5.js

I am new to p5.js and I am just trying to create a full screen canvas but I am getting a small white line at the bottom of the screen and I can't figure out why

```js
function setup() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    //background(0);
}

function draw() {
    background("#222");
    ellipse(windowWidth / 2, windowHeight / 2, 100, 100);
    fill("#07C");
    noStroke();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>p5.js starter</title>
    <style>
        body {
            /* padding: 0; */
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.4.1/lib/p5.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Uncomment below line to enable p5.sound -->
    <!-- <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.4.1/lib/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script> -->
</head>

<body>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is how it looks like locally

[image: p5.js white line at the bottom]

If you open the image in new tab you can notice the issue

Edit :
The issue is only happening in chrome it is fine in firefox and brave

Comment: Which browser gives this issue?

Comment: @anurag only happening in chrome it is fine in firefox and brave

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue in Chrome 98. See [this live sketch](https://editor.p5js.org/phentnil/sketches/0LKZ_A_Kz) to test it. It's most likely not something with your code, though. What version of Chrome are you experiencing this issue?

Comment: @phentnil I was working locally that is why you could not reproduce the issue in the web editor I am using chrome 98 btw

Comment: If it's only local and in Chrome, it's still not likely something with your code. It could be something with the browser styles or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the styles to

```
        * {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        body {
            overflow: hidden;
        }
```

Fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

the first thing you should try doing is adding + 10 to  `windowHeight` or whatever number that is enough to remove this white line, if that doesn't work  then it might do with the browser you're using.

Comment: adding +100 to windowHeight fixes the issue but wanted to know if their is a problem in my styles and also only happening in chrome it is fine in firefox and brave